# Test jsonp rest app response using httpbuilder

Tags: json, rest, jsonp, httpbuilder

Hi
I'm trying to build up a rest Service which provide JSON response.
Yesterday i figured about what is JSONP, why to use it an so and so.
Today i would like to make some test with my new version of my service.
To test it, i use HTTPbuilder. But i can't get it working correctly.
Here is the start of my test:

```
 def client = new RESTClient("http://localhost:"+SERVER_PORT)
 def resp = client.get(path:'/music', contentType:JSON);
```

And here is the error i got:

```
ATTENTION: Error parsing 'application/javascript' response
 net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String
```

How can i help httpbuilder to understand that the response is a JS callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i was a littel dumb on this one.
The accepted content type must be ContentType.ANy